# Submit directly from a modal dialogue jquery

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog, form-submit

I have a modal dialogue with jquery which populate a div,I need instead of populate a div to submit directly ,How can I achieve that,
What I did: I have a button when I click it opens a modal dialogue,with this modal dialogue I add data and I save data in another div,below the code:

My part of code :

```
            <script>
                    $(function() {

                            $( "#MyDialog2" ).dialog({
                                    autoOpen: false,
                                    height: 300,
                                    width: 700,
                                    modal: true,
                                    buttons: {
                                            "ADD": function() {

                                                    $('#keyword_new_name').val($('#keyword_new_nameadd').val());
                                                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                            },
                                            "Cancel": function() {
                                                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                            }
                                    },
                                    close: function() {
                                            $('#keyword_new_nameadd').val("");
                                    }
                            });

                            $( "#newKeyword" ).click(function() { $( "#MyDialog2" ).dialog( "open" ); });
                    });
            </script>
```

HTML looks like that:

```
     <div id='MyDialog2' >
                <table cellpadding='11' >
                    <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Name:</td><td><input type='text' name ='keyword_new_nameadd' id='keyword_new_nameadd' size ='35' /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <form method="POST" action="">

            <div>
                <table cellpadding='11' >
                    <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Name:</td><td><input type='text' name ='keyword_new_name' id='keyword_new_name' size ='35' /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>

                <input type='button' value='NewKeyword' id='newKeyword'  />
                <input type='submit' value='addKeyword' id='addKeyword'  />

            </form>
```

Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to directly submit your form, right after (or instead of... not sure which you need)

```
$('#keyword_new_name').val($('#keyword_new_nameadd').val());
```

add

```
$('form').submit();
```

Personally I would give the `<form>` and ID and use that instead

```
$('#myFormId').submit();
```

Comment: $('#keyword_new_name').val($('#keyword_new_nameadd').val());this was for populate the div from the value from the modal dialogue

Answer (score 0):

I got it I added

```
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    $("#add_keyword").click();
```

add_keyword is the ID of 1 of my submit buttons